# how to display form values in popup box according to their respective Id's

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem in showing posted values in pop up box. When I click on book now it is showing only one id values for all.
Ex: if I click on 1st row on book now it is showing 1st row values, but if I click the 2nd row on book now it is showing 1st row values only.

```
          <span>Book now</a> <!--<div class="disp"><p>-->

          <div id="light" class="white_content"><label>Email:</label><?=$vehicle->Email; ?> </p><p><label>Mobile:</label><?=$vehicle->Mobile; ?></p>
          <p><form id="form_<?php echo $vid;?>" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <?php //echo $_REQUEST['email'];?>

                  <p>
                   <input type="hidden" name="vehicleid" value="<?php echo $vid;?>" id="vehicleid" />
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1_<?php echo $vid;?> " value="1" id="bstatus<?php echo $vid;?>" onClick="idForm(<?php echo $vid;?>)" />
                      Conform</label>
                    <br />
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1<?php echo $vid;?>" value="0" id="bstatus1<?php echo $vid;?>" onClick="idForm(<?php echo $vid;?>)" />
                      Not Conform</label>
                    <br />
                  </p>

                </form><a href = "javascript:void()" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><b>X</b></a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how id works, you need have unique id for each div. Anticipating that you have a loop in place, you can add a counter or a incremental id while creating a div, something like below:

```
<div id="light_<?php echo $id;?>" class="white_content"><label>Email:</label><?=$vehicle->Email; ?> </p><p><label>Mobile:</label><?=$vehicle->Mobile; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately there is a conflict with the popup. When I add this id the pop up is not opening.